# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' while reading from AVRO using Python

Tags: python, avro

```
from avro import io, datafile
import pprint
OUTFILE_NAME = "demo.avro"
rec_reader = io.DatumReader()
df_reader = datafile.DataFileReader(open(OUTFILE_NAME, 'r'), rec_reader)
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
for record in df_reader:
    pp.pprint(record)
df_reader.close()
```

I am  getting this error

`"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'".`

IF anybody can guide me whats the mistake, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're reading a binary file, you must use `'rb'` as mode when opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python3, a regular string is `unicode`, and does not have a `decode` method.  A bytestring does.

I don't know anything about `avro`, and you don't show the error stack.  But it is a good guess that `datafile.DataFileReader` expects a file that has been opened in `rb` mode. Or maybe it takes the filename, and does the `open` itself (`numpy` readers accept either a filename or opened file).